# Перехват событий клавиатуры в linux системе

Tags: c++, linux, c

Задача состоит в создании прослойки между ядром и пользовательским приложением ( либо какой-либо другой вариант) для перехвата событий клавиатуры и их дальнейшей модификации. Что можете подсказать? Не знаю, куда именно стоит начать копать.

UPD: 
Задача сводится к написанию прослойки, которая будет обрабатывать нажатия клавиатуры и, в зависимости от собственного внутреннего состояния, отправлять их активному окну оболочки.

Comment: *Не знаю, куда именно стоит начать копать* — например, можно начать с изучения уже написанного до вас: google://linux+keylogger

Comment: linux я могу ошибаться, но родные сообщения от клавиатуры в linux модифицировать нельзя и реализация подмены нажатых клавиш не возможна (разумными затратами)

Comment: Если под "перехватом событий" понимается обработка нажатий на клавиши стрелок и иже с ними, то проще всего - использовать библиотеку ncurses.

Comment: Спасибо. С keylogger'oм я частично ознакомился. А как можно отправить событие нажатия кнопки клавиатуры активному окну оболочки?

Comment: окна-то тут при чём? вы как-то определитесь всё-таки, что вам нужно. // *С keylogger'oм я частично ознакомился* — т.е., вы даже не вводили такой запрос в поисковик. ну что ж, удачи вам в поиске «того, не знаю чего».